# error: cannot convert ‘ignition::gazebo::v3::components::Component<std::vector<double> to ‘float’

Tags: gazebo-ignition

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am trying to get the **joint's position** for my **Cessna plugin** using this method

```
float rudder =  _ecm.Component<components::JointPosition>(this->joint[5.0]);
```

which gives me this error in the line shown **above**

```
 error: cannot convert ‘ignition::gazebo::v3::components::Component<std::vector<double>, ignition::gazebo::v3::components::JointPositionTag, ignition::gazebo::v3::serializers::VectorDoubleSerializer>*’ to ‘float’ in initialization

     float rightFlap =  _ecm.Component<components::JointPosition>(this->joint[3.0]);
```

**code snippet**

```
    void CessnaPlugin::PublishState(EntityComponentManager &_ecm)
    
    {
        IGN_PROFILE("CessnaPlugin::PublishState");
      
        // Read current state
    
        double propellerRpms = _ecm.ComponentData<components::JointVelocity>(this->joint[6.0])/(2.0*M_PI)*60.0;
    
        float propellerSpeed = propellerRpms / this->propellerMaxRpm;
    
        float leftAileron = _ecm.Component<components::JointPosition>(this->joint[2500]);
    
        float leftFlap =  _ecm.Component<components::JointPosition>(this->joint[1.0]);
    
        float rightAileron =  _ecm.Component<components::JointPosition>(this->joint[2.0]);
     
       float rightFlap =  _ecm.Component<components::JointPosition>(this->joint[3.0]);
    
        float elevators =  _ecm.Component<components::JointPosition>(this->joint[4.0]);
    
        float rudder =  _ecm.Component<components::JointPosition>(this->joint[5.0]); ----> error occurs here

}
```

**joint entity as declared**

```
std::array<ignition::gazebo::Entity, 7> joint;
```

**parameters**

```
   private: static const unsigned int kLeftAileron  = 0;

    private: static const unsigned int kLeftFlap     = 1;

    private: static const unsigned int kRightAileron = 2;
 
   private: static const unsigned int kRightFlap    = 3;

    private: static const unsigned int kElevators    = 4;

    private: static const unsigned int kRudder       = 5;

    private: static const unsigned int kPropeller    = 6;
```

Any solution for this?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26812/error:-cannot-convert-%E2%80%98ignition::gazebo::v3::components::component%3Cstd::vector%3Cdouble%3E-to--%E2%80%98float%E2%80%99/) by [Adwait](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/42410/adwait/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 7 on 2021-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

refer this [issue](https://github.com/ignitionrobotics/ign-gazebo/issues/769).

Thanks to [Diego Ferigo](https://github.com/diegoferigo) for this answer.

A joint in its most generic form can have more than one degree of freedom. This is the reason why the JointPosition component stores a vector:

ign-gazebo/include/ignition/gazebo/components/JointPosition.hh

Lines 38 to 39 in a41cf80

```
 using JointPosition = Component<std::vector<double>, class JointPositionTag, 
                                 serializers::VectorDoubleSerializer>;
```

In 99% of cases, you're using either a revolute or prismatic joint, therefore the vector contains only one element:

```
const auto& jointPosition = _ecm.ComponentData<components::JointVelocity>(jointEntity);
assert(jointPosition.size() == 1);
const double position = jointPosition[0];
```

---

Originally posted by [Adwait](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/42410/adwait/) with karma: 7 on 2021-04-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0